# Import modules like `import <module> as <alias>` in Powershell

Tags: powershell

So here's what I'm trying to do - in Java, for instance, if I want to use an `ArrayList<>` in my program I just write

```
...
import java.util.ArrayList
...
```

And then from there on I can just write `ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>...` etc.

Also, in Python I can, for instance, write something like

```
from numpy.random import randint
```

And again, in my program I can just write `randint(something)`.

Is there an equivalent way of doing this in PowerShell? I'd like to use a `System.Collections.ArrayList`, but I can't find any syntax online.

Comment: If you need to do this a ton, you can write a factory function at the top of your script that returns an ArrayList and give it a short name (or better yet give it a propernaming convention Verb-Noun name and create a short alias). Then use that whenever you need a new ArrayList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference a namespace with a [`using namespace` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-6):

```
using namespace System.Collections
```

Then you can omit the namespace when creating a new object

```
$arr = New-Object ArrayList
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create `New-Object` for`System.Collections.ArrayList` :

```
$arr= New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
```

> The New-Object cmdlet creates an instance of a .NET Framework or COM
>   object.

After that you can use `ArrayList` methods :

```
$arr.Add('test')
```

Comment: What if there's several places I want to create such an object? Do I _have_ to write `New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` or is there a shorter way, e.g. through some kind of an import statement, so that I can just write `New-Object ArrayList` thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

I will throw this in just for fun. First, create a function:

```
function New-ArrayList{
    New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
}
```

Next create an alias:

```
New-Alias -Name al -Value New-ArrayList
```

Then use it:

```
$myArrayList = al
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option is probably the one given by @laika, but you can also use `Type Accelerators`.  These used to be easy to work with, but from PSv3, things were made a bit more difficult (probably to force you to use better techniques).  Built-in accelerators include the standard .NET types such as `int`, `string`, `DateTime`, etc, and more obscure things such as `System.Management.ManagementObject`.  You can get a full list like this:

```
[PsObject].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::Get
```

To create your own, do this:

```
[PsObject].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::Add('ArrayList',"System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

You can then use the new accelerator like this:

```
$arrayList = New-Object ArrayList

$arrayList.Add(1)
$arrayList.Add(2)
$arrayList.Add(3)

$arrayList
1
2
3
```

Note that these last only for the current session, so would need recreated everytime you wanted to use them.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I agree in that using `namespace` is probably the most readable and straightforward solution, but this is pretty cool as well.